# Change Mongodb query result in place

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Restaurant is a Mongoose model. I tried to change things in place and it doesn't work:

```
  Restaurant.find({}, function(err, results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      delete results[i].__v;
  }
```

I think `results[i]` is a model object. I tried to see check the property descriptors with the following and it's says `undefined`:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(results[i], '__v')));
```

Why doesn't delete on the object work? And how come I can't see the property descriptor?

**EDIT**:
So it's a Mongoose document. But what in Javascript parlance can an object such as a Mongoose document be based on something else other than a Javascript object? Some wrapper base on internal C code or something?

Answer (score 3):

`results` isn’t a Javascript Object and then you can’t use `remove`

You can Convert in Javascript Object with `results.toObject()` [doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-toObject)

or you can do 
`Restaurant.find({},{lean:true}`[doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)

and then you can do `delete results[i].__v;`

Comment: If it's not implemented by a JS object, what is it?

Comment: It's [Mongoose Document](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document-js)

Comment: Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not MongooseDocuments.

Comment: Yes thanks to you I get it. Though in Javascript parlance, what can be an Mongoose Document an object of if it's not also a JS object? Every object in JS is a kind of JS object according to what I know. How do you make something that's not?

Comment: {lean:true} doesn't work. It still doesn't allow me to add or delete fields.

Comment: find().lean().exec() does work though.